# Appcode doesn't autocomplete third party libraries

Tags: ios, swift, intellij-idea, rx-swift, appcode

Recently I'm giving a hand to my iOs team(coming from Android) and I'm trying to use Appcode to keep all my IntelliJ keybinds and shortcuts. However, even if I can work with Appcode and everything compiles and works well. Some of the libraries that I use on the application doesn't work with AppCode autocomplete. I can't access the base code or do nothing. However if I write the code without any kind of autocomple/helper the code compiles and works well.

For example using RxSwift:

[image]

I have been reading and Jetbrains says that this issue was [fixed on 2018 edition](https://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2018/01/appcode-2018-1-eap/). But I'm using 2020 edition and I keep having this troubles.

So, my question is: how can I make Appcode show third party libraries methods and classes on the autocomplete?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, AppCode does support completion in third-party libraries. In your case the problem most likely is specific to RxSwift or your particular project setup. For example, there is this known problem with RxSwift, see comments for a workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-19258

If the workaround doesn't help, feel free to contact AppCode support for more specific troubleshooting or create an issue in the issue tracker.